# Python: delete element of one txt file from another txt file

Tags: python, integer

I hope you are well.

I have two txt files: data.txt and to_remove.txt

data.txt has many lines, and each line has several integers with spaces in between. One line in data.txt looks like this: 1001 1229 19910

to_remove.txt has many line, each line has one integer. One line in to_remove.txt looks like this: 1229

I would like to write a new txt file which has data.txt without the integers in to_remove.txt
I know the first element of each line of data.txt does not have any of the elements of to_remove.txt; so I need to check all non-first elements of each line with each integer in to_remove.txt

I wrote to code to do this, but my code is far too slow. data.txt has more than a million lines, and to_remove.txt has few hundred thousand lines

Would be useful if you can suggest a faster way to do this.

Here is my code:

```
with open('new.txt', 'w') as new:
    with open('data.txt') as data:
        for line in data:
            connections = []
            currentline = line.split(" ")
            for i in xrange(len(currentline)-2):
                n = int(currentline[i+1])
                connections.append(n)
            with open('to_remove.txt') as to_remove:
                for ID in to_remove:
                    ID = int(ID)
                    if ID in connections:
                        connections.remove(ID)
            d = '%d '
            connections.insert(0,int(currentline[0]))
            for j in xrange(len(connections)-1):
                d = d + '%d '
            new.write((d % tuple(connections) + '\n'))
```

Comment: just a quick comment: you don't need to copy the current line, and don't need to read the "to_remove" file again for each row you are processing (store it in memory once at the beginning).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit messy, so I've re-written rather than edited. The main way to improve your speed is store the numbers to remove in a `set()`, which allows for efficient O(l) membership testing:

```
with open('data.txt') as data, open('to_remove.txt') as to_remove, open('new.txt', 'w') as new:
    nums_to_remove = {item.strip() for item in to_remove} # create a set of strings to check for removing
    for line in data:
        numbers = line.rstrip().split() # create numbers list (note: these are stored as strings)
        if not any(num in nums_to_remove for num in numbers[1:]): # check for the presence of numbers to remove
            new.write(line) # write to the new file
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. And my apologies for my messy code.

What your code does is not what I'd like to do. I was not clear enough in my question. Please allow me to explain again.

Suppose data.txt has the following data
1 2 3 4
2 4 5 6 7
3 4

And suppose to_remove.txt has the following data
4
5

I would like new.txt to be the following 
1 2 3
2 6 7 

In other words, I'd like to delete all occurrences of integers in to_remove.txt, and if any of the lines in data.txt is left with just one integer, I'd like to discard that line as well.

Thanks once again.

Comment: @user58925 Do you understand what my code does? If so, perhaps you can modify it to meet these new requirements. It's hard for me know exactly what you want because I don't have your data files

Answer (score -1):

I developed a code to answer my question using the code in the some of the answers, and the suggestion in the comment to the question.

```
def return_nums_remove(): 
    with open('to_remove.txt') as to_remove:
        nums_to_remove = {item.strip() for item in to_remove}
    return nums_to_remove 
with open('data.txt') as data, open('new.txt', 'w') as new:
    nums_to_remove = return_nums_remove()
    for line in data:
        numbers = line.rstrip().split()
        for n in numbers:
            if n in nums_to_remove:
                numbers.remove(n)
        if len(numbers) > 1:
            s = '%s '
            for j in xrange(len(numbers)-1):
                s = s + '%s '
            new.write((s % tuple(numbers) + '\n'))
```